# Javascript: How to keep track of absolute positions (top/left) of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, events, ecmascript-6, event-handling

I need to get all the positions of a html element (div) based on its position on the screen. I'd like something like `addEventListener` that would send the element's positions whenever the screen changes (on resize/on zoom/on scrolling etc - whenever the position of an element changes). Is that possible with pure Javascript?

Comment: Please include an [mcve]

Comment: you're looking at it the wrong way. To work with addEventListener you need to have an Event in mind, so once it's triggered, the callback provided to the addEventListener is executed.
Now, an event can be triggered by yourself, programatically, like at the end of some function, or by some user's action, i.e. some click.
In this case you would probably need to listen to some window event

Comment: I don't see why you could not. The window resize and scroll events could be used and then request the information of the geometry/positon of your desired element(s). You may not have access to all the events you want. For example, there is not currently an event that let's you know when the size of an element has changed but you can read about that on MDN under mutation event.  One issue you may have with the resize and scroll events is that they fire many times per second; so, you may want to throttle the execution of the event handler so it does not execute as often as the events fire.

Comment: @Gary thank you very much, that's exactly what I've tried to figure out, if there exists any simple/unified way to do it, but didn't find anything. Nice to be sure that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not intended to be a complete answer but two examples of what I meant in the comment.  Perhaps it will be of some assistance in setting up what you are trying to do.  There is not a pre-built method to do what you want but that doesn't mean you cannot do it.

The first one is used to adjust the screen layout if the user alters the browser's default font size. There is no event for that so I use the `focus` and `blur` events on the window and keep track of the size of an off-screen element in order to test whether the default font size changed. It is captured on `blur` and tested on `focus`.  The resizing takes place in the sizeTable function.

```
window.addEventListener( 'focus', () => fontSizeProxy( false ), false );
window.addEventListener( 'blur', () => fontSizeProxy( true ), false );
fontSizeProxy.base = document.getElementById('sz_gauge').offsetHeight;
fontSizeProxy.size = document.querySelector('div.tabs').clientWidth;

function fontSizeProxy( b )
 {
   if ( b )
     { fontSizeProxy.size = document.querySelector('div.tabs').clientWidth; }
   else // focus event
     { setTimeout( done, 1000 ); };

    function done()
     {
       // Get w after the delay so browser can reset completely.
       let w = document.querySelector('div.tabs').clientWidth;
       if ( w !== fontSizeProxy.size )
         {
            fontSizeProxy.size = w;
            fontSizeProxy.base = document.getElementById('sz_gauge').offsetHeight;
            sizeTable( nav.n );
         }; // end if
       w = null;    
    } // close done
 } // close fontSizeProxy
```

The second example is a `resize` event and is shown because it throttles the event so that the function sizeTable doesn't execute as often as the event fires.  You may want less of a throttle than the 500ms used here.

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', resize, false );

function resize()
 { 
    if ( !resize.clear ) 
      {
        resize.clear = setTimeout( () => { resize.clear = null; sizeTable( nav.n ); }, 500 );    
      }; // end if
 } // close resize
```

The concept for what you want is here, I think.  You just need to make your version of a sizeTable function that queries and adjusts what you want to execute when the events take place and you may have to listen for numerous events to execute the same function, as done here.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation, it helped me understand the problem much better. I'll add the missing lines and I think it will suit my needs very nicely.