# Keep content position on window resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For reprodution set scroll thumb to end of scrollbar and change window size:
https://jsfiddle.net/coryphoenixxx/zLq3u4sn/36/

How to stop this and keep sizes of inner box in vw?

```
<html>
<body>
<div class='box'>
  <div class='inner-box'></div>
  <div class='inner-box'></div>
  <div class='inner-box'></div>
  <div class='inner-box'></div>
  <div class='inner-box'></div>
  <div class='inner-box'></div>
  <div class='inner-box'></div>
  <div class='inner-box'></div>
  <div class='inner-box'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.box {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 12vw;
  border: 0.1vw solid black;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.inner-box {
  margin: 1vw;
  min-width: 7vw;
  height: 7vw;
  border: 0.1vw solid black;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps make use of the `resize` event. Track the `scrollTop` or `scrollLeft` position and `scrollHeight` or `scrollWidth`, or percentage such as `scrlPct = scrollTop/scrollHeight` after every scroll change. Then in the resize handler, apply the percentage to the newly sized scroll container, such as `scrollTop = scrollPct * scrollHeight`.  You may want to throttle it so that it doesn't fire every time resize fires. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58069005/javascript-how-to-keep-track-of-absolute-positions-top-left-of-a-div/58117982#58117982) for example to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found solution

```
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

let boxScrollPct = 0;
let ignoreScroll = false;
box.addEventListener('scroll', ({ target: t }) => {
  if (ignoreScroll) return;
  boxScrollPct = t.scrollLeft / (t.scrollWidth - t.clientWidth);
});

let timeOutId = null;

window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
  ignoreScroll = true;
  box.scrollLeft = boxScrollPct * (box.scrollWidth - box.clientWidth);
  
  clearTimeout(timeOutId);
  timeOutId = setTimeout(() => {
    ignoreScroll = false;
  }, 50);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I may be misunderstanding exactly how your resize and scroll events interact but I don't think this is quite what you want in terms of throttling.  Since `resize` fires many times a second, if user were to drag the window size with the mouse, code in the resize handler would set `scrollLeft` and alter display of it many times a second.  The setting should be inside the `setTimeout` so that it is set once per your chosen delay. Since you're not invoking a function that alters the DOM from the `scroll` event handler but only storing the values, it doesn't appear necessary to test `ignoreScroll`.

Comment: I suppose you could place a `setTimeout` in the scroll event handler also and record the values only after a certain delay to try to record it after the scrolling was complete rather than every time it fires.  I don't know what would happen on a touch device if scrolling was still in progress and the user rotated the phone.  In other words, what happens if resize fires while scroll is still firing?  There a [note here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event) about iOS and some devices firing scroll event only after scroll is complete.